# pulling location.href or window.location from fire fox without it being encoded

Tags: firefox, url, encoding

I'm passing a url through google translate and in my location bar on Fire fox, the url looks as it should:

[http://72.14.235.104/translate_c?hl=en&langpair=en|ru&sl=ru&tl=ru&u=http://something.something/something/.....orig_term%3Dмалярии](http://72.14.235.104/translate_c?hl=en&langpair=en|ru&sl=ru&tl=ru&u=http://something.something/something/.....orig_term%3D%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)

I want to grab the orig_term and apply its value other places on my page as it loads.  The problem is, despite showing accurately in the location, the window.location, window.location.href, location.href all show values with the orig_term encoded.  I've tried de-encoding the encoded value, but its representation is :

Ð¼Ð°Ð»ÑÑÐ¸Ð¸

Anyone know why this works great in IE but not in Fire Fox?

Answer (score 1):

I just put this URL in my Firefox 3 address bar:  [http://www.google.com/search?q=малярии](http://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)

I can get the right data back if I [decodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeURI.asp) the href.  I replaced the above URL in my address bar to test it.

```
javascript:alert(decodeURI(window.location.href))
```